# ¿Cómo agrego un ScrollBar horizontal a un DataGridView y que el contenido se adapte al tamaño de las columnas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me encuentro realizando un `paginador`, utilizando un `DataGridView`, pero como las `columnas` de la tabla son muchas, no se adaptan al `Grid`.

Y eso pasó desde que puse esta línea para que las `columnas` se ajustaran al tamaño del nombre de las mismas.

> dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, las últimas `columnas` no se ajustaron y estuve revisando sus propiedades del `scroll`, y por defecto está en `Both`, pero solo aparece el `scroll vertical`. Las demás opciones son : `None, Vertical y Horizontal`.

También quisiera saber de una vez, cómo modificar los `nombres` de las `columnas`, si alguien es tan amable de ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: Puede ver este post por si te vale [Enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150084/ajustar-contenido-al-tama%C3%B1o-del-datagrid-c/150131#150131) Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

Realicé un `for` que ajusta los `encabezados` o `columnas`con el `contendio` de estos, y automáticamente me pone el `scroll horizontal` y se ajusta el contenido al `grid`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
  dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
}
```

Resultado final:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]